# How to press Ctrl+0 (Zero) using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, virtual-keyboard

I want to send the keys Ctrl and zero using Selenium WebDriver APIs

I tried the below code but not working

```
 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("F000").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
```

Looking for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both these work for me:

A nice WebDriver approach

```
String ctrlZero = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "0");
driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).sendKeys(ctrlZero);
```

and the pure Java approach working on a higher level:

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_0);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use unicode characters , I guess this will work -

You must make this change in your code -

```
Actions action =new Actions(driver);
    action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0030')).perform();
```

Let me know if are facing any problems after this change.You can check the unicode table here - 
http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf

Comment: This is not working.Actually ctrl+0 is the shrtcut to set the zoom of IE browser to 100%. But it is not working

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions or errors. If any please post them?

Comment: Don't use numpad 0, it will not work.I'll check if it works by pressing 0 key.

Comment: can you try sendKeys("0") instead of sendkeys("F000")

Comment: Not working, I tried the sendKeys("0") also.  I am not getting any error but unable to set the zoom level of IE

Comment: I tried your code. but it is not working in my case. Any way thanks for your help